# Custom includes association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following table

```
Users(user_id, name, last_name)

Relationships(user_id, spouse_id)
```

I want to run the following query

```
person = Relationships.includes(:person).where(:name => 'David')
```

But I don't want the related person to be associated by the `user_id`. I would rather it be associated by the `spouse_id` only for this specific query.

Comment: take a look at this [example](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?view=asciicast)

Comment: can you provide the model name , as I can see there are something missing , here you have define user , relationships what about person ? you have user and person 2 model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails is perfectly content to allow multiple associations to the same table, providing they use a different foreign key.

In this case, you'd have something like this:

```
class User
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :spouses, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: :spouse_id
end
```

`User.first.spouses` would then be a collection of all relationships where the user's `id` was present in the `spouse_id` field.